# why do you have to malloc large data structures on the heap?

Tags: c, stack, malloc, stack-overflow, heap-memory

I remember talking about how the stack memory addresses grows down and the heap's grows up, but they occupy the same strip of memory. If that is the case why do some large data structures causes a stack overflow, but are perfectly fine on the heap?

Comment: The stck is traditionally limited, while the heap can make use of the whole memory.

Comment: @Devolus, that contradicts the OPs (correct) observation that traditionally stack memory addresses grow down and the heap's grow up. So they can meet anywhere in between.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie, why would this be a contradiction? A stack overflow occurs when you run out of stackspace, however that is determined. It has nothing to do with available memory as this depends on the architecture.

Comment: Limited stack size is a function of the operating system, not the language or underlying hardware (usually).  The motivation is to make sure no one process grabs all available memory if it goes rogue (such as through a badly-written recursive call) and threatens the stability of the overall system.  Of course, the same thing can happen if you go crazy on the heap,

Answer (score 3):

First, ignoring the historical oversimplification you've heard, there's a fundamental reason you need to use `malloc` for large objects rather than automatic ("stack") storage: only `malloc` has an interface by which it can report unavailability of the memory. If you enter a function with `char foo[1000000000];` in its body, on real-world stack based implementations, yes the stack pointer will be adjusted by 1000000000 but at that point who knows whether it points to free memory you can use as part of the stack or over top of some other unrelated memory. Some implementations (GCC's `-fstack-clash-protection`) will adjust it a page at a time and probe each page to produce a fault on the first *guard page*, thereby crashing your program rather than clobbering unrelated memory, but that's not a desirable outcome either. Whenever there's a possibility of failure, you need a channel through which that failure can be reported and handled.

Now, on to why the historical "heap grows up, stack grows down" explanation is wrong:

1. It only works when there is only one stack. In a multithreaded program there is one stack for each thread. If you wanted to position them all so that they could grow down by gigantic margins, you'd hardly be able to create any threads at all in a 32-bit memory space. In a 64-bit one it would be possible, just by the vastness of the space, but problematic (and most 64-bit systems don't really have 64 usable address bits anyway).
2. "The heap" and "the stack" are not the only things in your memory space, and "the heap" is not even a meaningful concept. Yes, historical `malloc` implementations used a growing fixed "heap range" for most allocations, but often exempted very large ones from that, instead performing individual `mmap` and `munmap` for each of those. But more importantly, other things live in this space - your program's executable code, executable code and data segments for shared libraries, etc. And on modern systems, the locations at which these are placed are randomized to mitigate the consequences of program bugs. This means they could be placed anywhere between what you want to think of as the "top of the heap" and "bottom of the stack", limiting how far either could grow contiguously.