# Why can't we have large VLA and (partially) replace malloc

Tags: c

Typically, we use malloc() when we don't know the needed size in advance, like this (with checking/error handling etc removed):

```
FILE * fp = fopen(path, "rb");
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
ssize_t length = ftell(fp);
rewind(fp);
char* buffer = malloc(length * sizeof(char));
fread(buffer, 1, *length, fp);
fclose(fp);
free(buffer);
```

we need to use `char* buffer = malloc(length * sizeof(char));` instead of `char buffer[length];` because the size of stack is very limited. My question is, as C supports variable-length array, **at least for local variables**, what stops us from making stack much much larger and just use stack memory instead?

I indeed find [one answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67078965/why-do-you-have-to-malloc-large-data-structures-on-the-heap). It raises a valid point: `malloc` has an interface by which it can report unavailability of the memory. But is this the ONLY reason that `char* buffer = malloc(length * sizeof(char));;` works and `char buffer[length];` doesn't?

Let me summarize some points raised by comments/answers:

0. `malloc()` returns `NULL` to indicate allocation failure while VLA does not have this design, so program can only crash if system's memory is exhausted;
1. We can't return local VLA from callee function to caller due to its local scope;
2. We can't use `realloc()` to adjust the size of VLA dynamically;
3. VLA is not a required feature in ISO C standard, so it might not be supported on some platforms.

(But as shown in the above example, in many cases, we just want a huge local VLA whose size is known at runtime but will never change once it is known. But still we must use `malloc()` for it)

**EDIT:**
Many people are finding the intention of the question unclear, "why the hassle and not just use `malloc()`?". Well the intention is simple: I am trying to reduce (if eliminate is not practical) the use of `malloc()` so that we save some mental burden to make sure all return paths free() my `malloc()`ed memory. It is sort of like localized/rudimentary RAII in C.

Comment: The last example is just wrong. Change `char* buffer = malloc(length);` to `char** buffer = malloc(length * sizeof(*buffer));`

Comment: One thing to note is that all ISO C compliant compilers are required to support `malloc`, but none are required to support variable-length arrays. As far as the ISO C standard is concerned, it is an optional feature (see [§6.7.6.2 ¶4 of the ISO C11 standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.2p4)). For example, the compiler Microsoft Visual C++ does not support variable-length arrays (even when compiling C instead of C++).

Comment: "What stops us from making stack much much larger?" Well, operating system limits for one, and secondly, each thread has its own stack, so if you want a huge stack, each thread becomes super heavy.

Comment: But note, @AndreasWenzel, that C23 will require support for VLAs passed as arguments to functions but still won't require support for local variables that are VLAs.  The meaning of `__STDC_NO_VLA__` changes between pre-C23 and C23.  You'll always be able to write `int function`(size_t n, Data a[n]) { … }` but you won't necessarily be able to write `int function2(size_t n) { Data a[n]; … }`.

Comment: @CraigEstey revised the question accordingly to make everything consistent.

Comment: I'm not sure that your final examples mean what you intend. `char *buffer[length]` is an array of pointers to `char`, and I'm not sure what `char buffer[] = malloc(length)` is supposed to be.

Comment: @tadman this is the part I am not sure, my understanding is that stack is utilized upon function call, so if we dont use it, OS wont mark it as being used. If you mean to say, the OS reserves the entire stack up front, then this is indeed a valid concern. But I am not sure if this is the case.

Comment: @adabsurdum updated the original question to fix this

Comment: Another advantage of `malloc` is that its allocated memory can be resized with `realloc`, whereas variable-length arrays cannot be resized once created.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel this is indeed a valid point, but having large VLA is still convenient in many cases, just like in my example, more often than not, we know the size of the VLA and that is not going to change at least during this particular function call. And we just use it locally, but still we have to use `malloc()`.

Comment: In your example code, the size of the data is determined by the size of the file. The available stack space, at any point during execution, depends on many variables (such as depth of nested function calls.) Even after testing every which-way, would you have confidence that there will be room for the VLA? "Compile with a larger stack size" is tantamount to "compile with a huge fixed array size, whether its used or not."

Comment: @Fe2O3 your last statement is something I want to be sure. Do you mean that the OS will handover enough memory that is enough to accommodate max stack size upfront, regardless whether the space is actually used or not? To put it another way, say the max stack size of my particular OS/compiler (not sure which one decides max stack size) is 100MB, when my program starts, it occupies 100MB of memory, even if it uses only 4bytes?

Comment: @D.J.Elkind That's my understanding, yes. AFAIK, there is a default quantity assigned by the linker (and can be specified by a compile argument)... I wouldn't worry too much, unless you think you need a larger stack. The memory is there, in modern systems, whether it's used or not. Gone are the days of `near` and `far` memory having different costs to utilise...

Comment: `void easy(int count) { int *arr = malloc(count * sizeof(*arr)); arr[count - 1] = 37; free(arr); }  void oops(int count) { int arr[count]; arr[count - 1] = 37; }  int main(void) { int count = 9000000; easy(count); oops(count); return 0; }`

Comment: @CraigEstey what do you mean by `oops()` here?

Comment: @D.J.Elkind Other then the lifetime, because VLAs live in the stack, one will get a stack overflow if one creates a large enough object.

Comment: Because it would virtually never help, is the real answer. malloc'ed memory is rarely ever used in the function that allocates it, so using auotmatic storage is a no go. Even in the example you gave, memory-mapping the file is probably a better approach.

Comment: @ikegami emmm I dont see how memory-mapped file could help...I simply read the file from the given file path...

Comment: Yeah, the slow way. If you're going to read the whole file, you get a speed boost by just mapping it to memory.

Comment: @ikegami i am not sure what is your understanding of "memory-mapped file". My understanding is that it is for interprocess communication/shared memory/etc. For just loading the file from file system to memory, the speed depends on the hard drive's IO only.

Comment: VLA is about the *types*, not about storage nor lifetime. The `typedef int T[n];` is essence of "VLA-ness". One can VLA on stack: `T arr;` or heap `T* arr = malloc(sizeof(T));`. There is no recovery from failure of stack-base allocation. The `int a[n];` can fail in a very same way as `int a[100000];` or a very deep recursion.

Comment: @tstanisl sorry I dont get your point that "VLA is about types". In my understanding, VLA is nothing but an array, just its size can be decided at runtime. As simple as this.

Comment: @D.J.Elkind, "VLA" is a mental short cut for "array of VLA type with automatic storage-duration". It is not that size of array is runtime-defined, it is about the **type** of array is runtime-defined. C23 makes support for VLA types mandatory while only object with automatic storage of VLA type are optional.

Comment: Please read [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22530363/whats-the-point-of-vla-anyway/54163435#54163435) describing what VLAs are really about and how those "runtime-sized arrays on stack" is just a small part of their funcitonality

Comment: Re "*My understanding is that it is for interprocess communication/shared memory/etc.*", You can create shared memory using `mmap`, but that's not what I said.  (I didn't use the word `mmap`.) It said to map the file to memory. That literally makes a file appear as a range of memory. /// Re "*For just loading the file from file system to memory, the speed depends on the hard drive's IO only*", No.

Comment: @tstanisl, The OP is specifically asking those with automatic duration. They're interested in not having to free the result (as evidenced by their desire to use it as a replacement for `malloc`, and by a C++ parallel they gave in the comments). They're using the mental shortcut you yourself described. Any talk of non-automatic storage VLA is not relevant. Heck, they could have asked about `alloca` instead of VLAs, and the question and an answer would be pretty much the same.

Comment: @ikegami, yes but is has not much to do with VLAs. The only advantage of VLAs is a tempting syntax. It is difficult to tell what OP is asking for. Making stack bigger? In Clang C++ one could use a reference to VLA. : `auto &arr = *(int(*)[n]) malloc(...);` to have an array with arbitrary storage.

Comment: @tstanisl, Re "*It is difficult to tell what OP is asking for.*", No. Please refer to my previous comment where I explain it if you find it unclear. /// Re "*In Clang C++*", The question is tagged [tag:c], not [tag:c++].

Comment: @ikegami, so what the question is? "what stops us from making stack much much larger and just use stack memory instead?". Answer is nothing. It's platform thing totally outside of C standard entirely.

Comment: I find it weird that people don't blink if recursion is mentioned, but the second a stack is mentioned "oh that's not C". But yeah, that's pretty much it. But there's a few other issues. (Lack of ability to create a variable number of blocks. Lack of ability to return the value. Lack of out-of-memory detection. Each thread has its own stack.)

Comment: `oops` --> "stack overflow".

Comment: @ikegami "Heck, they could have asked about alloca instead of VLAs, and the question and an answer would be pretty much the same."->yes essentially the intention is just to reduce (if eliminate is not practical) the use of `malloc()` so that we save some mental burden to make sure all return paths `free()` my `malloc()`ed memory.

Comment: @tstanisl @ikegami yes this for for C only, if we have C++, we may just any RAII-enabled container like `std::vector`

Comment: @CraigEstey I guess this is the purpose of the question, usually stack is small, may be 8MB in size? But if my computer has 16GB memory, why not making the stack 16GB in size? so as long as I dont try to push too hard, I wont have stack overflow.

Answer (score 8):

One main reason: the lifetime of a VLA, like any locally defined array, ends once the scope it is defined in ends.  So you can't use it to return a block of memory from a function.

For example, this is invalid:

```
int *get_array(size_t size)
{
    int array[size];
    return array;
}
```

But this is fine:

```
int *get_array(size_t size)
{
    int *array = malloc(size * sizeof *array);
    return array;
}
```

You also can't create a linked list of more than a trivial size if you need to rely on locally created variables.

```
struct list node1 = { 1, NULL };
struct list node2 = { 2, &node1 };
struct list head = { 3, &node2 };
```

This only goes so far before things get unwieldy.  And again, there's the problem of returning the address of a local variable.

```
struct list *get_node(int value)
{
    struct list node = { value, NULL };
    return &node;     // INVALID
}
```

Comment: What you said is a valid point. However, as I mentioned in the original question, "at least for local variables", that is, as long as the variable is kept local. But in a lot of cases, just like my example, we just need a huge local array, but still we need `malloc()`--if we can use VLA, then we can save a lot of `free()` in different return routes (but sure we may use `goto` to centralize all routes into one, but that is still not as convenient as we have auto free, just like `std::unique_ptr` in C++)

Answer (score 1):

The main reason why it is bad to allocate big items on the stack is because the stack is a fundamental part of the program, necessary for it to function as intended. It is not just used for raw data storage but also to store return address and parameters etc during function calls. As well as for local, temporary variables. The compiler is using the stack all over the place when generating your program. Whereas it will never use the heap unless explicitly told to do so.

As your program executes, the stack pointer ebbs and flows, as different parts of it need more or less stack - not necessarily trivial to foresee or estimate at compile-time. Run out of stack space and your program will crash in horrible ways. Therefore it is universal good practice to avoid allocating large objects on the stack: no matter is you are programming a x86_64 with seemingly endless memory, or if you are programming some lousy 8-bit PIC microcontroller with 100 bytes of stack and an artificial stack limit to function call depth.

Whereas a segment allocated on the heap *is* just raw data storage, it is not used for *anything* else but to store the data you put there. By convention, the OS is also using heap memory when dealing with huge chunks of data and it is therefore the natural way in which a process can get more memory as needed.

Also check out my answer here: [What gets allocated on the stack and the heap?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/277536)

Comment: I am afraid you repeated some of the simpler part of the thing I already know. Not sure if you aware, my question is not about them.

Comment: @D.J.Elkind It rather sounds as if your question is an endless moving of goal posts each time a new answer is posted...

Comment: @D.J.Elkind, C standard never mentions concept of a "stack" or a "heap". It is an implementation detail. Technically, the compiler could use implicit `malloc` for allocation of automatic VLA and place implicit `free` when it goes out of scope. But still it would not be possible to recover from allocation failure because there is no convention for passing this error to a program.

Answer (score 0):

*It raises a valid point: malloc has an interface by which it can report unavailability of the memory.*

That is the point. If stack is exhausted you have no choice: programs stops with an error. By using `malloc/free` you have the hands on some fallback strategy.

Comment: The problem is, do you have any documents, say from gcc's manual/C standard committee's meeting minutes/books from Dennis Ritchie, Ken Thompson/etc that mentions this reason?

Comment: @D.J.Elkind All the people involved in the things you mention already know how computers work. The C committee wouldn't waste time explaining how a stack works in some meeting. Dennis Ritchie wouldn't need to explain this to Ken Thompson (and they both programmed ancient dinosaur computers anyway, so I'm not sure why their thoughts on the matter would be anywhere close to relevant).

Comment: @Lundin what you said is something accepted as conventional wisdom which can most likely satisfy your interviewer. But no, this is not the point of the question. The question is about something deeper.

Comment: @D.J.Elkind No, the question is "what stops us from making stack much much larger and just use stack memory instead?"

Comment: @D.J.Elkind I remember that Thompson&Ritchie who designed C&Unix knows how a stack works and that the primary usage of it is to manage call/return + some few local data. Efficiency in mind probably. There is many arguments against VLAs (in C) (there is some pros, much more weaker than cons IMHO), https://www.phoronix.com/news/Linux-Kills-The-VLA. You need VLA? malloc/free is an almost cost-free good alternative choice. Remember, C was designed Unix in mind, not as the general purpose language it became... And, the name of this site.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès, the VLA types are actually dedicated for handling multidimensional arrays and for passing arrays of any dimensionality to functions where VLAs really shine. The automated VLAs on stack have some  safe niche applications but those are rare and usually have alternatives.

Comment: @tstanisl for "passing arrays of any dimensions", do you mean something like this: `void fvla(int m, int C[m][m]);`? (example from page 132 of [C11 draft](https://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1570.pdf))